# Taking word at point interactively

Tags: interactive, words, thing-at-point

I would like to adapt this function for the interactive case, that takes the word at point.

```
(defun rules-tablet (word)
  "Shorten word at point according to specific rules."

  (interactive)

  (let* ( (rx-regexp) (rx-rep) )

    (add-to-list 'nscrip word)

    (setq rx-regexp (rx (seq "ow" eow)))
    (setq rx-rep (rx "w"))
    (add-to-list 'nscrip (s-replace-regexp "ow\\>" "w" word))

    (setq rx-regexp (rx (seq "ch" eow)))
    (setq rx-rep (rx "c"))
    (add-to-list 'nscrip (s-replace-regexp "ch\\>" "c" word)) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `(interactive (list (word-at-point)))`.

Really, you can *ask Emacs* your question, almost verbatim. You already know how to use `interactive` (except you didn't use it to provide the arg the function requires).

All you need to ask Emacs is about a function that returns the "word at point".  For that, command `apropos` is your friend:

**`M-x apropos word at point`**

And instead of dumping your entire code into the question, all you need to show in your question is the first two lines: `defun` and `interactive` -- all the rest is irrelevant to your question.